# How to make card gradient in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable fun Gradientcard() {

val horizontalGradientBrush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
    colors = listOf(
        Blue,
        lightBlue
    )
)




Card(modifier = modifier = Modifier
            .background(brush = horizontalGradientBrush),shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)){
    Text(
        text = "sub 1",
        
    )
}
```

This method made background of card as gradient but not the card. Card color is still white.

Output

[image: cardgradient]

Comment: Evening after changing it dint worked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using `modifier` in `Card` try creating `Box` layout inside `Card` and add gradient code inside it.

```
Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(175.dp),
            elevation = 4.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .background(
                        /* Your code*/          ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Card Gradient Background",
                    
                )
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cut that modifier from the`Text`, and paste it in the `Card`

```
Card(modifier = ... /*Paste*/){

}
```

Comment: I tried this method it dint changed card color.i have attached output in question section